# Are summations the same as a definite integral?

Tags: integration, summation

So I was looking at my teacher's solution to a problem, and it starts with a summation, which she converted to a definite integral:

$$\sum_{x=0}^{x=n} \sum_{y=0}^{y=n} |x-y| = \int_{0}^{n}\int_{0}^{n} |x-y| dy dx$$
$$= \int_{0}^{n} \Biggl( \int_{0}^{x} (x-y) dy +  \int_{x}^{n} (y-x) dy \Biggr) dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{n} x^2 - nx + \frac{n^2}{2} dx$$
$$=\frac{n^3}{3}$$

However, I tried to convert the integral back to a summation and do the calculation that way...just to see if the answer would be the same, and it ended up been differen:
$$\int_{0}^{n} \Biggl( \int_{0}^{x} (x-y) dy +  \int_{x}^{n} (y-x) dy \Biggr) dx$$
$$\sum_{x=0}^{x=n} \Biggl( \sum_{y=0}^{y=x} (x-y) + \sum_{y=x}^{y=n} (y-x) \Biggr) $$
$$\sum_{x=0}^{x=n} \Biggl( x^2 -nx+ \frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2} \Biggr)$$
$$= \frac{n^3}{3} + n^2 + \frac{2n}{3}$$

I thought because you could make the original summation in to a integral, you could turn the integral back in to a summation midway, but is that not correct?

Comment: $$\sum_{x=0}^{x=1} \sum_{y=0}^{y=1} |x-y| = 2 \neq \dfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{1} \Biggl( \int_{0}^{x} (x-y) dy +  \int_{x}^{1} (y-x) dy \Biggr) dx = \dfrac{1}{3} \neq 2$$

Comment: You can't convert summation into integration that easy

Comment: @TimurBakiev The first section is solution provided to me by my teacher, is it not correct? The second section was me thinking that was correct and reversing it. 
The final answer in the solution I was provided seems to be correct in terms of what it is based on: Average seek distance for a hard disk with n tracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be shown that $$\sum_{x=0}^n \sum_{y=0}^n |x-y| = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$$

and $$\int_{0}^{n}\int_{0}^{n} |x-y| \,dy\, dx = \frac{n^3}{3}$$

The integral may be used as an approximation to the discrete summation. However, strictly speaking, they are not equal.

You calculated the exact discrete sum already!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My teacher never mentioned it was an approximation, so I assumed that she did the "conversion" because they were equal (as she put a equal sign between the integral and the summation). So it's good to know that the integral is only an approximation!